# "Error while loading manipulator"

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm continually getting the following error under Eclipse Galileo while trying to install the WTP Web Page Editor plugin:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while loading manipulator.
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.loadDelegate(LazyManipulator.java:54)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.getConfigData(LazyManipulator.java:108)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction.installBundle(InstallBundleAction.java:76)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction.execute(InstallBundleAction.java:29)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ParameterizedProvisioningAction.execute(ParameterizedProvisioningAction.java:35)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Phase.mainPerform(Phase.java:129)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:72)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:44)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:54)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningUtil.performProvisioningPlan(ProvisioningUtil.java:389)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProfileModificationOperation.doExecute(ProfileModificationOperation.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningOperation.execute(ProvisioningOperation.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.ProvisioningOperationRunner$1.run(ProvisioningOperationRunner.java:94)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

One blog said Eclipse Galileo doesn't play well with Java 1.6 (what??), so I've tried running Eclipse with Java 1.5 but that hasn't helped. Has anyone else had this problem and been able to get around it?

---

**Edit** BTW, below the error in the error log it also says

`session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]javax.mail 1.4.0.v200905040518, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to follow the various suggestions mentioned in the [bug 277242](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=277242)

Also check your eclipse.ini:

> More generally, the error you're seeing can happen when we cannot read "`-startup`" since we use this to position the install.area.

As suggested by [Jelle van Geuns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949338/jelle-van-geuns) in the comments (and confirmed by [Halfstop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898218/halfstop)):

> I found that one MacOS there are two folders (MacOS and Eclipse) with two separate sets of configuration files.
>   Each had an '`org.eclipse.equinox.launcher`' startup jar in the plugins sub-folder, but with slightly different versions.
>
> The Eclipse executable resides in the MacOS folder.
>   But the `eclipse.ini` there was set up to look for the startup jar under `Eclipse/plugins`, but with the wrong version.
>
> Solution that worked for me was to copy both versions of the `startup.jar` to both the plugins sub-folders.

[Halfstop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898218/halfstop) confirms:

> I copied all of the what was in Eclipse to the MacOS directory and this solved it.

Comment: This bug does not mention the fact that spaces between "-startup" and the value that you assign can cause "-startup" to not be read correctly. I already had "-startup" in my eclipse.ini but the value was on the same line. Putting the value on a new line resolved this problem for me.

Comment: I found that one MacOS there are two folders (MacOS and Eclipse) with two separate sets of configuration files. Each had an 'org.eclipse.equinox.launcher' startup jar in the plugins sub-folder, but with slightly different versions. 

The Eclipse executable resides in the MacOS folder. But the eclipse.ini there was set up to look for the startup jar under Eclipse/plugins, but with the wrong version. 

Solution that worked for me was to copy both versions of the startup jar to both the plugins sub-folders.

Comment: For me, like @JellevanGeuns said, I have a MacOS and Eclipse directory. I copied all of the what was in Eclipse to the MacOS directory and this solved it.

Comment: @Halfstop OK. I have included Jellle's and your own comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: One more comment on this. I continued to have issues with Eclipse, probably needed to keep copying files around. The permanent solution for me was to delete the Eclipse app and my ~/.p2 directory and reinstall from scratch. Eclipse upgrades are notoriously bad processes.

Comment: @Halfstop I usually avoid any upgrade of an existing instance of Eclipse: I just install a new Eclipse in a new folder, and use a new dedicated workspace.

Comment: I do too @VonC, but I figured it might work since Eclipse is now a legit Mac app. I was wrong.

Comment: @Halfstop I understand the spirit and hope ;) But... no.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem today. The answer provided by [VonC et al](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) helped to locate the problem but didn't quite fix it.

In my case, the location specified in `-startup` within the `MacOS/eclipse.ini` was incorrectly looking in the `../Eclipse/plugins` folder rather than the `../MacOS/plugins` folder.

I corrected the path and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

try to `chown -R your_user_name:your_user_name /path/to/eclipe`

Answer (score 0):

Try edit 
`Eclipse/configuration/config.ini`.

Make sure `osgi.instance.area.default=` value is right workspace. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the above answers adequately resolve this issue.  I've found that, with a number of our eclipse derivative RCP products, that on some linux machines plugins will fail with log entries like this one:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2017-02-23 12:00:49.492
!MESSAGE An error occurred while installing the items
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2017-02-23 12:00:49.492
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=TIBCOBusinessStudio-4.0, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.tibco.eclipse.p2.installer 1.1.3.20161130, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2017-02-23 12:00:49.492
!MESSAGE Error while loading manipulator.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while loading manipulator.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.loadDelegate(LazyManipulator.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.LazyManipulator.getConfigData(LazyManipulator.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction.installBundle(InstallBundleAction.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction.execute(InstallBundleAction.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ParameterizedProvisioningAction.execute(ParameterizedProvisioningAction.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.mainPerform(Phase.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningSession.performProvisioningPlan(ProvisioningSession.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProfileModificationJob.runModal(ProfileModificationJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

The reason this happens (I suspect) is that the actual file name of the config file is compared with the absolute name by the lazyloader.  In my case the home dir is a symlink, so the two names don't match.  The resolution was to edit the eclipse.ini (or whatever yours is called) and ensure that all the paths referencing the eclipse home dir are fully qualified and do not rely on symlinks.

Comment: this problem also happens when you use p2.director to install plugins and you specifiy `-destination` with a relative path https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549150